# Angular 8 remember data

Tags: angular

I am using angular 8, I have a component with a search form, I would like the form to remember the data entered by the user when browsing from one page to another. How should I proceed ? any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a simple code example of your scenario. Preferably with the addition of a stackblitz

Comment: you can use localStorage or a singleton storage service, or even store the data in a parent container component. All of these will hold data for you whilst you switch pages. Only localStorage will persist data in case of app refresh though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store data in local-storage,

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
Make sure to stringify value, for example if you have an object
localStorage.setItem(itemName, JSON.stringify(itemData));
```

OR for individual key-value pairs

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ token: token, name: name }));
```

And to retrieve data from localstorage

```
user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
```